# Moving large amounts of data from specific rows within a column to equivalent areas within another excel file

Tags: python, excel, vba, sas

I’m trying to make the data update process more efficient for my company and I would like some ideas on how to effectivize this procedure. Currently I have to update specific excel files on a per month basis and I’m using a vlookup to link the specific data between the files using identifiers such as ”gd1” to make sure the vlookup grabs the correct specific data point of a row within a column to the equivalent point in my other excel file that I update.

My question is.. Would VBA be able to do a better job at this than a conventional vlookup that links to the data excel file? Would Python be able to do it better? What would be some of the things to think about when creating a VBA / python code for this task?

Thanks in advance!

I’ve tested around with some basic VBA scripts but run into the problem that it only updates specific rows but not all of them and sometimes misses the correct location.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.